# Generate random number each time and don't include last number

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, repeat

I have 4 colors. I want to make it so that the player can't be the same color 2 times in a row. When a player collides with an object, the `RandomColor()` is called. So this function is called many times during the game and sometimes the player does not change his color.

```
 using UnityEngine;

 public class ColorManager : MonoBehaviour {

     public SpriteRenderer player;
     public string playerColor;

     public Color[] colors = new Color[4];


     private void Awake()
     {
         RandomColor();        
     }

     public void RandomColor()
     {
         int index = Random.Range(0, 4);

         switch (index)
         {
             case 0:
                 player.color = colors[0]; //colors[0] is orange
                 playerColor = "orange";
                 break;

             case 1:
                 player.color = colors[1]; //colors[1] is pink
                 playerColor = "pink";
                 break;

             case 2:
                 player.color = colors[2]; //colors[2] is blue
                 playerColor = "blue";
                 break;

             case 3:
                 player.color = colors[3]; //colors[3] is purple
                 playerColor = "purple";
                 break;
             }    
     }    
 }
```

Tried using while loop, do while loop, but I'm obviously doing it wrong, since I receive the same color twice in a row sometimes. It would be great if anyone figures it out and explains how/why it works, because I spent a big chunk of time on the issue and I am very curious.

Comment: youz have 4 colors, when choosing a new color reroll your random until the players color is different from the one he currently has ....

Comment: A better technique: make a collection that contains only the currently-legal colors, then choose a random element from that collection. Using immutable collections will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need a function that can generate a random number with exclusion. Below is what I use for that:

```
int RandomWithExclusion(int min, int max, int exclusion)
{
    int result = UnityEngine.Random.Range(min, max - 1);
    return (result < exclusion) ? result : result + 1;
}
```

Each time you call it, you need to store the result in a global variable so that you will pass that to the `exclusion` parameter next time you call it again.

I modified the function so that you don't have to do that each time it is called. The new `RandomWithExclusion` function will do that for you.

```
int excludeLastRandNum;
bool firstRun = true;

int RandomWithExclusion(int min, int max)
{
    int result;
    //Don't exclude if this is first run.
    if (firstRun)
    {
        //Generate normal random number
        result = UnityEngine.Random.Range(min, max);
        excludeLastRandNum = result;
        firstRun = false;
        return result;
    }

    //Not first run, exclude last random number with -1 on the max
    result = UnityEngine.Random.Range(min, max - 1);
    //Apply +1 to the result to cancel out that -1 depending on the if statement
    result = (result < excludeLastRandNum) ? result : result + 1;
    excludeLastRandNum = result;
    return result;
}
```

**Test**:

```
void Update()
{
    Debug.Log(RandomWithExclusion(0, 4));
}
```

The last number will never appear in the next function call.

For your specific solution, simply replace

```
int index = Random.Range(0, 4);
```

with

```
int index = RandomWithExclusion(0, 4);
```

Comment: Would you explain why is (min, max -1) why is there a "-1"? Does that mean I will never get the number 3? Because the numbers are 0, 1, 2 and 3. And if it randoms on 3, it will go 3 - 1, and result in 2, meaning 3 is never going to be an option?

Comment: No. I am subtracting 1 from the max in `Random.Range` then adding that 1 back to the result depending on the `if` statement outcome. This is a technique I use to remove the number I want to exclude.  You will get the number 3. Do a test with the test code in my answer in the `Update` function and you will see. Modified the answer to fix a simple issue and added more comment to it

Comment: It took me pretty long to get what's happening with the -1. Last question (I sincerely hope), why do we need to know if this is the first run or not?

Comment: That's simple. If it is a first run, there is no need to do **exclusion** because exclusion requires  the **last generated number** to function. The problem is that the first run does not have a last generated number. Only after the first run, you will have a last generated number. We use the `firstRun` variable to determine this so that we don't have to do exclusion if it is first run because we don not have last random number yet until first run.

Comment: Excelent. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add a judgement if the RandomColor returns a same color as prev one, just call it again, easy right?

Comment: You run into freezing/locking problems like one of the [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47968494/3785314) answers. You can fix that by calling it in a coroutine and waiting for a frame but that will slow that the game.